# Trying to render a React-Bootstrap Modal on Plunker

Tags: reactjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/f8Z4bucIq0WblkNSIMP5?p=preview

```
  render: function() {
      console.log('render', this.state)

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Click to get the full Modal experience!</p>

        <ReactBootstrap.Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          bsSize="large"
          onClick={this.open}
        >
          Launch demo modal
        </ReactBootstrap.Button>

        <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
            <span>The Modal</span>
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The JSX seems to be compiling. The Modal component is available. The show prop is being set when you click the button. The Bootstrap CSS is there.

But the Modal always shows on page load even though its show prop is false.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took a look at your plunker and saw that you were using an older version of react-bootstrap. I think this was your problem I changed the version to a newer one and it worked.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-bootstrap I just used the v0.28.3